# Headsepline next to chapter and section title instead of below

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage

In [**this thesis**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13507/36835) - made with the **memoir** class - the author uses **headseplines** next to the header content instead of below:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the same with **KOMAscript** and **scrlayer-scrpage**, for both the even pages with the chapter title and the odd pages with the section title?

Unlike the linked example I'd like to get:

*even page:*

chapter title _________________________________________________

*odd page:*

__________________________________ section number section title

Page numbers are not relevant, as they are in the footer.

---

Here a MWE to play with:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RequirePackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\scshape}
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{0.1pt}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello World!}
\section{Section One}
\blindmathpaper
\blindmathpaper
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

---

I tried to abolish the **headsepline** and modify the `\chaptermarkformat` and `\sectionmarkformat` using `hrulefill`, which seems to be a good way. But I can't get it right.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RequirePackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}[1]{\scshape \hspace{2ex} \hrulefill}
```

[image]

(chapter name should be on left side, spacing wrong)

---

With

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}[1]{\hrulefill \hspace{2ex} \thesection \hspace{1ex} \rightmark }
```

the odd page looks all right, but it seems to me that it should be done a little different. E.g. why do I need set the spacing manually here: `\thesection \hspace{1ex} \rightmark`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `\hrulefill`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\lehead{\headmark{} \hrulefill}
\rohead{\hrulefill{} \headmark}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\scshape}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

Or if you want to use the `headmarks=.1pt` option:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=scrheadings.head.odd,
  contents={\GetLayerContents{scrheadings.head.below.line}}
]{scrheadings.head.odd.line}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=scrheadings.head.odd.line,
  evenpage
]{scrheadings.head.even.line}
\AddLayersToPageStyleBeforeLayer{scrheadings}%
  {scrheadings.head.odd.line}{scrheadings.head.odd}
\AddLayersToPageStyleBeforeLayer{scrheadings}%
  {scrheadings.head.even.line}{scrheadings.head.even}

\lehead{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\colorbox{white}{\headmark\strut\enskip}}
\rohead{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\colorbox{white}{\enskip\headmark\strut}}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\scshape}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! Regarding your additional edit: I finally used this two commands: `\def\verrulefill{\leaders\hrule width 0pt height 3pt depth -2.8pt \hfill}% 
\newcommand{\headseprule}{{\color[rgb]{0.75,0.75,0.75}\verrulefill}}` to modify thickness, color and vertical position of the line. Seems a little easier. Or what else is the purpose of the large second part of your answer?